# Array of abstract classes (interfaces) in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, interface, compiler-errors

I want to declare an array of interfaces and further get a pointer to the list of interfaces `Interface*`. But compiler (`GCC`) prints error `error: invalid abstract 'type Interface' for 'array'`. Code:

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual ~Interface() = default;

    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface {
public:
    void Method() override {
        // ...
    }
};

class ImplementationNumberTwo : public Interface {
public:
    void Method() override {
        // ...
    }
};

// there is an error
static const Interface array[] = {
        Implementation(),
        ImplementationNumberTwo(),
        Implementation()
};
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Defining an array of `Interface` requires that `Interface` can be instantiated.   It cannot.   You need an array of pointers (e.g. `Interface *`) or smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Interface>`).   I'll leave initialisation as an exercise - but it will differ from what you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an `Interface` object since it's an abstract type. Even if `Interface` were not abstract what you are trying would not work because of [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Instead you need to create an array of `Interface` pointers, e.g.

```
static Interface* const array[] = {
    new Implementation(),
    new ImplementationNumberTwo(),
    new Implementation()
};
```

In C++ polymorphism only works through pointers (or references).

Of course using dynamic allocation to create the `Interface` objects brings in new issues, like how those objects get deleted, but that's a separate issue.